# Bypass 404 error handling for JPG files in IIS6

Tags: iis-6, jpeg, custom-errors, web-config

I have the following setting in web.config file

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
```

It works nicely for missing pages but I don't want it to handle missing JPG files. The reason is that I have the "OnError" parameter for the pictures set in such a way that if the picture is not found (usually a pre-rendered thumbnail), it is created at that stage and I am suspecting the error handling is interfering with this.

Is there a way to make the custom error handle any file but JPG?

Thanks!